# Logs from @google-cloud/logging not appearing in Google Cloud's Logs Explorer for Cloud Run Job

Tags: node.js, terraform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I'm running a NodeJS app that utilizes the @google-cloud/logging library (version 11.0.0). I package this app into a Docker image stored in the Artifact Registry. Subsequently, I use Terraform to create a cloud_run_v2_job resource that references this image.

Within my app, I initialize the logging client like this:

```
const logging = new Logging();
const log = logging.log('myLog');
```

Then, I write logs like this:

```
const message = "My message"
const entry = log.entry({ severity: 'INFO' }, { message });
log.write(entry);
```

Surprisingly, these logs are not visible in the Logs Explorer. In contrast, if I employ a console.log statement, it appears as expected. To troubleshoot, I wrapped the logging code in a try-catch block:

```
try {
  const message = "My message"
  const entry = log.entry({ severity: 'INFO' }, { message });
  log.write(entry);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

No errors are logged, which suggests that the logging code is executed without issues.

Given these observations, I'm leaning towards a permissions issue. In my Terraform configuration, I attempted to add the appropriate permissions:

```
data "google_project" "current" {}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "cloudrun_logging_permission" {
  project = data.google_project.current.project_id
  role    = "roles/logging.logWriter"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${data.google_project.current.number}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

However, this didn't resolve the issue. I'm not very experienced with IAM and permissions in Google Cloud. Could someone point out if I'm missing something?

Comment: I'm still figuring out the same problem in Cloud Run for a job. What I've found is that the logs are stored, visible only after the execution is finished and stored as custom logs (without the labels and the extra feature in the web ui)